# What if there is conflict of hashing of keys in ArrayMap or SparseArray?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sparse-matrix, array-map

I have read many blogs for array map and sparse array where every where I am getting that

> ArrayMap contains two small array instead of one in a HashMap. The
>   first array (Hash-Array) contains the specified hash keys in sorted
>   order. The second array (Key Value Array) stores the keys and values
>   of the objects according to the first array. For reference below link is given
>   https://android.jlelse.eu/app-optimization-with-arraymap-sparsearray-in-android-c0b7de22541a

But no where I am getting that what happens if I have same hash code for two different keys in array map as in hash map it happens that in case having same key hash(collision) it appends the key value pair in linked list for a given bucket position for the next item.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the hashMap in ArrayMap when a hash collision occurs, instead of appending the key value pair in linked list for a given bucket position, for the next item it simply puts the value in next available position in second array. And for searching, **when a hash collision occurs, it walk though the second array until finds the desired values**.

Here it is described in provided doc:

> When we fetch an item, a binary-search is done on the Hash-Array to find a matching hash the index and then directly return the key-value pair from the second array (Key Value Array). If the key in the second array (Key Value Array), doesn’t match then a linearly walk is done over the second array (Key Value Array) to resolve the collision.

Comment: Hi @ruhul thanks for reply. Could you please refer any doc where it could be found that the collision item is referred to next index of the second array.

Comment: The text is quoted from the doc you've provided.  https://android.jlelse.eu/app-optimization-with-arraymap-sparsearray-in-android-c0b7de22541a

Comment: Yes it is for searching, but for insertion it is not clear. And if I am going through this link https://www.javatips.net/api/j2objc-master/jre_emul/android/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java here it is simply overwriting the previous object in put method.